# Restrict Upload Directories in Wygwam field

Tags: wygwam, file-uploads, file-manager

The site I'm working on has multiple upload directories with different permissions on them.

The content administrator is building public-facing pages and including PDFs via the page's Wygwam field, but by default Wygwam is selecting the first upload directory the content administrator has access to, which is not a public file directory (e.g. it selects "Private" instead of "Public", presumably because it appears first alphabetically).

Is there a way in my Wygwam field to specify what upload directories it can use, like in a file custom field? If there is, I'm not seeing it.

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You con configure each of your Wygwam configs to be restricted to a particular upload directory by going to Add-Ons > Modules > Wygwam > [your config name], and setting the Upload Directory setting.

Comment: Spot on. I had assumed from the labelling 'Basic' and 'Full' it referred only to the CKEditor toolbar. Thanks!